# Разовая перезагрузка страницы

Tags: javascript

Помогите, пожалуйста, реализовать разовую перезагрузку страницы. Пользователь заходит на сайт, страница один раз перезагружается и больше не перезагружается до следующей сессии.

Код получился примерно таким, но не работает. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.
Мне кажется, что я что-то напутала с ключами в sessionStorage.

```
var reload = 0;
if(sessionStorage.getItem(reload==0)){
    window.location.reload();
    reload=1;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы не только с ключами напутали,  но и вообще с алгоритмом решения.
Вам необходимо попытаться получить значение ключа `reload` из текущей сессии (`sessionStorage`). Если значение есть, то ничего не делать. Если нет, то записать значение в сессию, и обновить страницу.

Код для этих целей должен выглядеть следующим образом.

```
var reload = sessionStorage.getItem('reload');
if(!reload){
    sessionStorage.setItem('reload', 1);
    window.location.reload();
}
```